# Past notification appearing when app closes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I try to make an app that has to notify 4 deferent notification in a day for whole year this is my code when I run the code its work but the problem is if date was already passed for example 2014-03-12 01:12 the notification should not appear but it is appearing when the app close and I try with these as well `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` or `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotifications];`.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:@"2014-03-10 01:04"];
NSDate *myDate1 = [df dateFromString:@"2014-03-10 01:21"];
NSDate *myDate2 = [df dateFromString:@"2014-03-10 01:22"];
UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
n1.fireDate = myDate;
n1.alertBody = @"one";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n1];
UILocalNotification* n2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
n2.fireDate = myDate1;
n2.alertBody = @"uuu";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n2];
UILocalNotification* n3 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
n3.fireDate = myDate2;
n3.alertBody = @"ontt";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n3];
```

Comment: what can i add on code

Comment: Are you quitting the app or just navigating to home ? Also check this answer, cancelling notifications probably requires the notification object http://stackoverflow.com/a/3379196/366346

Comment: @2-Stroker just reminding app i try with that but its cancel notification only one