# How can I update the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] array?

Tags: iphone, arrays, edit, uilocalnotification

This may be more of a question regarding how to update arrays in general, but I have an app that is utilizing UILocalNotifications, and I want to allow users to select the notifications they have set, and edit them.

So what could I do to update an object at an index?

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] ??];
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could see this thread that explain well how to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158264/cancel-uilocalnotification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the `UILocalNotification` object, you can "reschedule" it by canceling the old notification with:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:aNotification];`

and scheduling a new one:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:aNotification];`

Answer (score 1):

You can not able to edit an already existing notification.

But you can able to cancel it by using `cancelLocalNotification`: and create a fresh notification.