# localNotification / uiTableView / delete row -> ERROR "invalid number of rows"

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, row, localnotification

**This is my ERROR:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I know what that means but I cant find my mistake in code. I know that I have to use NSMutableArry, only. Not a normale NSArray.This is the Point I think...

In my h. File:
NSMutableArray *notifArray, IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;

**CODE:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];

    }
```

**CODE:**

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    NSArray *_notifArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *notif = [_notifArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    <...>
```

**CODE:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            [notifArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            [myTable reloadData];
        }
    }
```

**CODE:**

```
- (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender {
    [eventText resignFirstResponder];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotification == nil)
        return;
    localNotification.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotification.alertBody = [eventText text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotification.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];


    [self.myTable reloadData];
}
```

---

If I change this line to a NSMutabelArray than I got an error, too. "Incompatible pointer types initializing "NSMUtableArray" with an expression of type "NSArray*"

```
---> NSArray *_notifArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

So what can I do, that it is possible to delete the row including a localNotification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THANKS A LOT!!!**

I think my Problem was at first a wrong code ;-) and at second I forgot that a notification displyed in a row are TWO THINGS! So I have to delete AT FIRST theNotification and second time theRow in my tableView ;-)

Here is my code - feel free ;-)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
           {

            // DELETE theNotification defined in (UITableViewCell *)tableView:{}
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notifcation];

            // DELETE theRow
            [notificationsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

            [tableView reloadData];
    }
```

}

**YEEAARRR Im so happy ;-) Im really new in coading anyway ;-) - So If anybody has a better way feel free to correct me :-)**

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the initilisation you can create the mutable array like this :

```
NSMutableArray *_notifArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]];
```

And you probably need to retain it as well.

Regarding the line deletion, I wonder about the call to reloadData. I don't think it is necessary, since the previous line DeleteRows... causes the update of the table view, and I even wonder if it could be the cause of your message. Of course it is called after DeleteRows but we have no real way of knowing how this is all sequenced, and if the reload queries numberOfRows before the DeleteRows is completed, then it can cause your message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,thanks for helping me, at first.

So after testing some code, my problem is now a nother I think. Or my code is better know ;-)

If I click on EDIT and DELETE one row, the row is fade out. It seems like the row is deletet. But after restart the app, the row with the old data is still there ;-(

One problem solved - one new in my code *arrrghhh

Comment: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {     
        //Delete the object from the table.
        [notificationsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
`

Comment: I thought about the table view more than the notifications, maybe you can complete the solution with this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158264/cancel-uilocalnotification