# How to cancel all UILocalNotification, if the user got reminded x many times?

Tags: ios, ios7, uilocalnotification

I have a situation with `UILocalNotification`. I know there is an answer how to [cancel a uilocalnotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158264/cancel-uilocalnotification)

My scenario is though:

- I would like to remind the user to use the app on daily basis.
- If the user doesn't use the app for three days, then I would like to increase the interval from daily to every three days.
- If the user still doesn't come back after 6 days, I would like to stop all notifications.

Reading the document it says there is this one method that is called when the app is running: `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`.  But this is only hit if the app is running at the time of event. What if the user doesn't come back?

Is there anyway my app could cancel all events after a certain number of inactive days have passed? I don't want to keep pestering the user, if there is no interest after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to setup all local notifications when you go to background.
So you same notification several times with different date - each of them are single notification (non repeated).

- after 1 day
- after 2 days
- after 3 days
- after 6 days

Each time user opens you up you clean all of them with "cancelAllLocalNotifications" - each time he goes to background you create them all.