# How to avoid duplicate notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, notifications, uilocalnotification

My app shows up a local notification when the user disables the Wifi from iOS system settings. But it shows **'n' number of notifications if the user turns on and off the Wifi for 'n' number of times**.

I would like to show the new notification only when the previous notification was cleared or user taps on the same to launch the app.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why don't you check whether the network status has actually changed when you receive the notification? if not, you can ignore _n-1_ notifications gracefully.

Comment: you should cancel all notification before setting new notification.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification]` before scheduling a new notification. It will cancel your notifications and user will receive only one notification.

For more check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158264/cancel-uilocalnotification/3334028).