# how cancel local single notification in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can u help me how to cancel local notification in iOS 10

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center removeAllPendingNotificationRequests];
[center removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers:@[ CYLInviteCategoryIdentifier ]];
```

`removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers` i cant understand

Comment: What about removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers can you not understand?  It removes all the pending notification requests whose identifiers appear on the array that you give it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel UILocalNotification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158264/cancel-uilocalnotification)

Answer (score 3):

While creating a Local notification, you can pass an identifier to each notification. Use the same identifier to remove the local notification.

Code to create local notification:-

```
NSString *identifier = @"Unique Identifier";
UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier content:content trigger:trigger]

[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
   }
}];
```

Code to Cancel Notification:-

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Identifier1",@"Identifier2", nil];
[center removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers:array];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotificationRequest *> * _Nonnull requests) {
        NSLog(@"count%lu",(unsigned long)requests.count);
        if (requests.count>0) {
            UNNotificationRequest *pendingRequest = [requests objectAtIndex:0];
            if ([pendingRequest.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier"]) {
                [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers:@[pendingRequest.identifier]];
        }
                }

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any of the above solutions. I don't cancel any single notifications. Rather, whenever the user runs the app I cancel ALL the local notifications and run the code that recreates them all with the new parameters, which will cancel any local notifications that need cancelling. Less code surface, less to test, creating notifications is generally an inexpensive operation. Many, many apps use this solution, consider whether you could use this yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to remove single local notification.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *allLocalNoti = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i=0; i<[allLocalNoti count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification* currentLocalNotification = [allLocalNoti objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = currentLocalNotification.userInfo;
    NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"]];
    if ([uid isEqualToString:uidtodelete])
    {
        [app cancelLocalNotification:currentLocalNotification];
        break;
    }
}
```

Happy Coding...