# Checking if a value exists in a NSDictionary for local notifications

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So im using local notifications to send a daily notification to the user, once the notifcation is added i add an id in the userInfo - NSDictionary. The user can remove the medication at any time which will cancel the notification which is why i add the id into the NSDictionary.

```
 var notification = new UILocalNotification();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string stringid = rnd.Next(1, 1000000000).ToString();


            notification.AlertBody = usermedid + "Please take " + dosage + " of " + medname;
            stringid = notification.AlertBody;
            App.BadgeCount = App.BadgeCount + 1;
            notification.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = App.BadgeCount;
            notification.FireDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(60);
            notification.RepeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute;


            var userInfo = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(new NSString("UsermeddosageID"),new NSString(usermeddosagetimeid));

            notification.UserInfo = userInfo;

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);
```

The code is inserting the id into the NSDictionary but for some reason it wont read it in my IF Statement. Can anybody explain why my code isnt working ?? Any help appreciated..

```
var array = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications;



        foreach (var item in array)
        {


            var userinfo = item.UserInfo;
            if (!userinfo.ContainsKey(new NSString(usermeddosagetimeid)))
            {

           UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification(item);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, if you want to cancel the notification which contains the key `usermeddosagetimeid`, the if Statement should be:

```
    if (userinfo.ContainsKey(new NSString(usermeddosagetimeid)))
    {

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification(item);

    }
```

Instead of `!userinfo.ContainsKey(new NSString(usermeddosagetimeid))`

BTW, [scheduledlocalnotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622993-scheduledlocalnotifications?language=objc) is Deprecated since iOS 10, you can use the [UNUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter?language=objc) class to schedule local notifications instead.

Comment: Thanks, so i changed my notifications to UnUsernotifications as off now, is there a way to cancel all them at once , eg when the user goes to log out ?

Comment: Try the solution is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43773809/10539446). And methods are:[removeallpendingnotificationrequ](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649509-removeallpendingnotificationrequ?language=objc) and [removependingnotificationrequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649517-removependingnotificationrequest?language=objc)